# Displaying different graphs in the same stock panel (amCharts)

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amstock

I'm using amCharts to display graphs and I need to display 2 graphs from different data providers it the same Stock Chart panel.

In amCharts tutorials, they displayed the graphs from the same data provider (one dataset), so when I tried adding another dataset, it didn't work! It only displayed the first graph.

Could anyone give me a tip or something?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Stock Chart will display a copy of a graph for each selected or compared data set.

So if you need to display a graph for several data sets, make sure the following two conditions are met:

- [`compared`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/DataSet#compared) is set to `true` for the second data set.
- [`comparable`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockGraph#comparable) to `true` for the graph.
- [`compareField`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockGraph#compareField) is set for the graph.

Here's a working example:

http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/1706af51ff69cf22b2d448cfb604b55b